# How to kill a process in a terminal inside emacs

Tags: emacs

When I code, I usually use multiple buffers in emacs. Some buffers with my code, and a buffer with a terminal emulator (M-x term), There I compile, execute interpreters, etc.

When I get an infinite loop in some computation, I cannot kill my process (As one could do with a normal terminal with Ctrl-C), since obviously the terminal embedded in emacs doesn't get the interrupt.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Ctrl-G often works inside an emacs buffer.

Comment: For me, Ctrl-C Ctrl-C sends a ^C to the terminal and I'm able to interrupt a running program.

Answer (score 23):

As mentioned in the comments, by [@ALiX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119737/how-to-kill-a-process-in-a-terminal-inside-emacs#comment188116_119737) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (2 times) worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you run a process in eshell，you can use ctrl c ctrl c to kill the process, otherwise you can kill the buffer using ctrl x k

Comment: Using GNU Emacs 25.2.2 in Terminator. Ctrl-C+Ctrl-C didn't work, but Ctrl-x k (which calls kill-buffer) did. But, you lose the buffer...

Comment: @AAAfarmclub if you're using `ansi-term` instead of `term`, then you should use `C-x C-c` (no, that won't exit your emacs)

Answer (score -1):

Use the key sequence `C-c C-k`.